# Выполняется редирект при повторном нажатии на кнопку Ajax jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

Такая проблема. На сайте код перехватывает переход по ссылке и он не происходит, но функция срабатывает. Однако после удаления(то есть срабатывания функции) удаление другого происходит с редиректом. Как этого избежать, помогите пожалуйста, проект горит. Движок Друпал 8.6.4.
Код на JS:

```
!(function ($) {
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
alert("second");
  console.log('Edit post!!');
  console.log('Event');
  console.log(event);
  console.log('Index!!!');
  console.log(settings.url.indexOf('add_to_inquiry_list'));
  console.log('Settings');
  console.log(settings);
 if (settings.url.indexOf('add_to_inquiry_list') != -1) {
    var trigger_menu = $('.rmm-toggled');
    if(!trigger_menu.hasClass('rmm-closed')) {
        trigger_menu.next('.nano').removeClass('.has-scrollbar').hide();
        trigger_menu.addClass('rmm-closed')
    }
    var search_block = $('#block-customautosearch-2');
    search_block.hide();
    $('a.header_search').removeClass('search-is-visible');
    if(!$('#b-pop-up-header').is(":visible")) {
        $('#b-pop-up-header').slideDown();
    }
    updateInquiryBlock();
 }

});

function updateInquiryBlock() {
alert('first');
$.ajax({
    url: '/get_count_cart',
    type: "GET",
    dataType : "html",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        $('.header_cart .counter').html(data);
    }
});
$.ajax({
    url: '/inquiry_block',
    type: "GET",
    dataType : "html",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        if(data != ""){

            $('.view-id-inquiry_list.view-display-id-block_1').html(data);
            $('.block-views-blockinquiry-list-block-1').addClass('fixed');
            $('.block-views-blockinquiry-list-block-1 .view-inquiry-list').hide();
            $('.block-views-blockinquiry-list-block-1 .view-inquiry-list').slideToggle("slow");
        }
    }
});
}

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Какой переход? По какой ссылке? Проект сгорит (.*

Ответ:

Используйте делегирование обработки событий.

Comment: То есть есть блоки с кнопками удаления, один раз отлавливается остальные нет

Comment: @ЭдуардКапучинский Вы думаете, мне все стало понятно? Нет, не стало. Тем не менее, я уже написал Вам, что нужно делать.